# setup project visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008

Tags: c#-4.0

I created desktop application using c# ( visual studio 2010 ) and a database using sql server 2008.
and i made a setup project but the question is :
1- how to put the database files in my setup project?
2- how can i attach the database automatically in sql server 2008 express when i install the application on another machine?
3- there is another solution instead of install sql server 2008 express on the other machines i'll install the application on it (there is no network between them )?